# Google Maps API draw; city, country, county, zip, state

Tags: google-maps, polygon

I am developing a visualization based off google maps. There are a few requirements the most complicated being rendering different areas on a google map. I need to render a few different sets of polygons based on zoom so maybe country, state, zip etc. It seems as if I will need an array of latitudes/longitudes which outline each of these areas. Are there any resources for these?

I see something called fusion tables which allow users to implement kml shapes on the map. However those dont seem to meet my requirements as I will need to add thresholds to each polygon which is rendered.

Lastly would it be a bad idea to render a large number of polygons. Would you expect me to run into issues? Lets say I render all 50 states, would this cause problems?

This will all be done on the fly and rendered programatically. I will be building these polygons to be renderd based on the contents of a report so what I am rendering can change with each execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can download many free shapefiles from the internet, for example @ http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata. Maxmind has also a free world geo database. You can download my PHP class concave-hull @ phpclasses.org and try to pull a shape from the Maxmind world geo database. You can also try my example @ http://www.phpdevpad.de/geofence/. It also gives the concave-hull. Personally I can also recommend Geonames for a zipcode world geo database.

Answer (score 0):

A Very Simply API exists for this query by zipcode,city,etc.. returns geoJson

https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/boundaries-io/overview

Image of the results in GooleMap[image]